# Getting CANON Mf241d scanner to work properly on Ubuntu

Tags: drivers, usb, canon, sane

I get a scanning problem with the CANON Mf241d copy/scan USB device.

The USB printer/scanner used to work perfectly with MAC. However, with Ubuntu 18.04, x64 the scanner does not work. The printer works fine with the driver from CANON. I installed SANE and all possible other drivers for scanning. I used the command

```
sudo scanimage -d pixma:04A92xx_0187xxxxx --format tiff > outfile.tiff
```

to do a test scan. The scanning starts, light moves, but the output image is a blank white one.

Any ideas why this is so?

Comment: Have you tried Simple Scan from the Ubuntu Software Center? Seems to work with most scanners out of the box as it were.

Comment: I used simplescan as well. The results are the same - blank white page after scanning.